# How can I collect all subdocuments into a single array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How can I collect all the subdocuments of a collection into a single array?  Say I have these documents in my collection:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52d709d8cdcc16fa35834320"),
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "upc" : "",
        }
    ],
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52d709d8cdcc16fa35834321"),
    "modified_at" : ISODate("2014-01-15T22:16:06.991Z"),
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "upc" : "",
        }
    ],
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("654321973387fa1fa7777777"),
    "start_date" : ISODate("2012-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "end_date" : ISODate("2012-11-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "upc" : "",
        },
        {
            "upc" : "",
        }
    ],
}
```

I don't need to do anyting fancy such as summing or calculating anything.  I just want to extract the subdocuments and end up with this:

```
[
    { "upc" : "123" },
    { "upc" : "456" },
    { "upc" : "789" },
    { "upc" : "012" }
]
```

I know there has to be a simple way to do this, but I am not having any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something similar, it can be achieved via the aggregation framework  (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). You could try a query like this ( Disclaimer : untested I usually build queries in C#)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
   { $unwind : "$items"}, 
   { $group: { 
      _id: null, 
      items: 
        { $push: "$items" } 
   }} 
}
```

If the syntax is correct, the query should hit every document and unwrap all the elements in the "items" array for every document. It then groups this together in a single document with "$group" and "$push" (operators explained here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). This *should* produces a structure as such:

```
{
   items:[
      { "upc" : "123" },
      { "upc" : "456" },
      { "upc" : "789" },
      { "upc" : "012" }"
   ] 
}
```

if it produces more you should add a $project step at the end of the pipeline (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

You can go further and optimize it by adding a $match step to filter the documents before unwinding, and even filter the results in the array ($match -> $unwind -> $match -> $group). (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Hope this helps and GL!

Comment: You left out an id in the group statement: 
{ $group: {
            _id: null,
            items: {$push: "$items"}
        }}

but otherwise it works.  Seems off that you have to use null as the _id but it works for now.

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I actually have that in my own code, it's been a while since I've used it. Good to know it works! I edited my answer and included your information.